# intersect a progress bar in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

Like the title says, I want to intersect a progress bar in Tkinter at some variable position. See the image for what I want to achieve, those red vertical lines that I edited into the image.
 [image]

The idea is to put text like "||" inside the bar and color it differently so it should look like what I want to achieve. I have seen a couple of examples with text being put into the progress bar, but it was always right in the middle of the bar which doesn't work for me. 
Here is the code that generates progress bars.

```
import ttk
from Tkinter import *
import random
master = Tk()

stl = ttk.Style()
stl.theme_use("winnative")
stl.configure("colour.Horizontal.TProgressbar", background="lime green")

for i in range(0,4):
    prgb = ttk.Progressbar(master, orient = "horizontal", length = 150, mode = "determinate", style = "colour.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
    prgb.grid(row=i, column=0, pady=10) 
    prgb["maximum"] = 1.0
    x = random.random()
    prgb["value"] = x


master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ProgressBar` widget doesn't support this. However you could create a small colored `Frame` and use `place` to put it on top of the progress bar.

Example:

```
for i in range(0,4):
    prgb = ttk.Progressbar(...)
    ...
    x = random.random()
    ...
    marker = Frame(prgb, width=4, background="red")
    position = random.uniform(0,x)
    marker.place(relx=position, rely=.5, anchor="w", relheight=.5)
```

I don't have access to a windows machine, but this is what it looks like on my mac:

[image]

Comment: Nice. A cool case use for `place()`. I will have to add this to my list of possible uses for `place()`.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: yeah, there are times when it's the exact right tool for the job.